# Returning a specific value from a database ASP.NET/C#

Tags: sql, asp.net

My question involves returning a specific value from a table in a database. I want to have it where after you login, it displays the name of the user's first and last name.

The table looks like this.

**Person**

```
UID(PK), FName, LName, Uname, Upass
```

How do I return just the `Fname` and `LName` so I can place it in a label?

Here is my current code. Keep in mind this is for the master page.

```
string strConn = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cloud2"].ConnectionString;

protected void btnlogin2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strCmd = "Select * From Person Where uname = @uname and upass = @upass";

    SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);

    SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, objConn);
    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", txtusername.Text);
    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upass", txtpassword.Text);

    using (objConn)
    {
        objConn.Open();
        SqlDataReader objDR = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (objDR.HasRows)
        {
            btnlogin2.Visible = false;
            txtusername.Visible = false;
            txtpassword.Visible = false;

            Response.Redirect("member.aspx");

            lblLogin.Text = "Logged in as: Test " ; //Display login name?
        }
        else
        {
            btnlogin2.Text = "Failed";
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Look at the example in the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First I'd refactor your logic a bit to maintain UI VS database calls a bit separate.  Secondly refactor your code to retrieve first and last name that uses code for your connection string, username, password, and outputs firstname and lastname.

```
string firstName, lastName;
if(ValidateUser(txtusername.Text, txtpassword.Text, out firstName, out lastName)
{
    //put your UI Logic and redirect in here
    lblLogin.Text = "Welcome: " + firstName + " " + " lastName;
}
else
{
    //login faild code
}

private bool ValidateUser(string strConn, string username, string password, out string firstName, out string lastName)
{
    firstName = string.Empty;
    lastName = string.Empty;

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(strConn))
    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * From Person Where uname=@uname and upass=@upass";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upass", password);

        con.Open();
        using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (r.Read())
            {
                firstName = r["FName"].ToString();
                lastName = r["LName"].ToString();

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. It was very helpful in finding a solution

Answer (score 1):

I would do three things:

- separate your UI logic from the database logic - don't access your database directly in the middle of a `button_Click` event handler......
- if you only need first and last name, then **only select** those two columns from the table!
- put all the disposable objects like `SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataReader` into `using(...) {...}` blocks so that they will be properly disposed after use

So my code would look something like this:

**UI layer**:

```
protected void btnlogin2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // call the database layer to get the first and last name
    FirstAndLastName data = GetFirstAndLastName(txtusername.Text, txtpassword.Text);

    if (data != null)  // something was returned - show it
    {
         lblLogin.Text = string.Format("You're logged in as {0} {1}", 
                                       data.FirstName, data.LastName);
    }
    else
    {
         lblLogin.Text = "Not logged in...."; 
    }
}
```

**Database layer**:

```
string strConn = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cloud2"].ConnectionString;

internal class FirstAndLastName
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

protected FirstAndLastName GetFirstAndLastName(string userName, string password)
{
    FirstAndLastName result = null;

    // if you only need FName und LName - then only select those two columns! 
    // don't just use SELECT * all the time because it's easy and because you're lazy
    string strCmd = "SELECT FName, LName FROM dbo.Person WHERE uname = @uname AND upass = @upass";

    // wrap everything into using blocks
    using(SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
    using(SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, objConn))
    {
       objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", userName);
       objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upass", password);

       objConn.Open();

       using(SqlDataReader objDR = objCmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
          if (objDR.Read())
          {
              result = new FirstAndLastName();

              result.FirstName = objDR.GetString(objDR.GetOrdinal("FName"));
              result.LastName = objDR.GetString(objDR.GetOrdinal("LName"));
          }
       }
    } 

    return result;
}
```

Comment: the separation of the database and UI is an excellent idea and the code you have provide is beautiful. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

```
string Name=objDR ["FName"].ToString() +  ["LName"].ToString()
lblLogin.Text = "Logged in as:"+Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the instance of `SqlDataReader` in following way:

```
WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cloud2"].ConnectionString; protected void btnlogin2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

string strCmd = "Select * From Person Where uname=@uname and upass=@upass";
SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, objConn);
objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", txtusername.Text);
objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upass", txtpassword.Text);


using (objConn)
{
    objConn.Open();
    SqlDataReader objDR = objCmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (objDR.Read())
    {

        string fName= (string)objDR["FName"];
        string lName= (string)objDR["LName"];
        btnlogin2.Visible = false;
        txtusername.Visible = false;
        txtpassword.Visible = false;
       Response.Redirect("member.aspx");
        lblLogin.Text = "Logged in as: Test "+fName+" "+lName; //Display login name?


    }
    else
    {

        btnlogin2.Text = "Failed";

    }
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your question how to return just the data you want from the query, or how to access it from the datareader?

It sounds like you might want ExecuteScalar(), and you can combine the fname and lastname fields in the query so you can just pull the one result:

```
string strCmd = "Select Fname + ' ' + LName From Person Where uname=@uname and upass=@upass";
SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, objConn);
objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", txtusername.Text);
objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upass", txtpassword.Text);


using (objConn)
{
    objConn.Open();
    var username = objConn.ExecuteScalar() as string;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        btnlogin2.Visible = false;
        txtusername.Visible = false;
        txtpassword.Visible = false;
       Response.Redirect("member.aspx");
        lblLogin.Text = "Logged in as:  " + username ; //Display login name?
    }
```

Edit: Just noticed a detail... you're setting lblLogin.Text after redirecting... so not thinking anyone's going to see it anyway.  Could add it to the querystring though and display it on member.aspx...

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like

`lblLogin.Text = "Logged in as: " + objDR.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("FName")) + " " + objDR.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("LName"));`

If memory serves, you probably also need to first call `objDR.Read();` to start iterating over the datareader.